# CUDA dim3 grid bypasses initialization

Tags: cuda, initialization

I want to work with a `dim3` grid in my CUDA Program but dont know the parameters at the moment of initialization (they need to be computed first). Is there an easy way to work around this?

Of course I can pass the parameters in the brackets of the kernel call, e.g. if my parameters are m and n: `kernel<<<m*n, thread_size>>>(...)`
But then I need to recompute the indices.

Answer (score 7):

`dim3` is an integer struct type defined in the file `vector_types.h` as

```
struct __device_builtin__ dim3
{
    unsigned int x, y, z;
#if defined(__cplusplus)
    __host__ __device__ dim3(unsigned int vx = 1, unsigned int vy = 1, unsigned int vz = 1) : x(vx), y(vy), z(vz) {}
    __host__ __device__ dim3(uint3 v) : x(v.x), y(v.y), z(v.z) {}
    __host__ __device__ operator uint3(void) { uint3 t; t.x = x; t.y = y; t.z = z; return t; }
#endif /* __cplusplus */
};
```

You can define a `dim3` variable as

```
dim3 grid(256);            // defines a grid of 256 x 1 x 1 blocks
dim3 block(512,512);       // defines a block of 512 x 512 x 1 threads
```

and use it as

```
foo<<<grid,block>>>(...);
```

In the case of your interest, you will have

```
dim3 grid(m*n);
dim3 block(thread_size);
kernel<<<grid,block>>>(...)
```

From the definition of `dim3`, it is not needed to explicitly initialize the fields of `grid` and `block`. Any field not provided during initialization is initialized to 1.

You can change the fields of `grid` and `block` with assignments like

```
grid.x = 512;
block.y = 64;
```

Comment: Yes, but i have to define dim3 at the start of the program, otherwise I get an error: "termination of control bypasses initialization of ...". But I dont know the parameters at the start, since I have to compute them first. Thats my problem. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: You can always just set some dummy values and then change them with grid.x=... grid.y=... grid.z=... Or you can just declare the variable after having computed its initial values?